# android simulate key press in another app

Tags: android, keyboard

I am new to android and have a requirement for an app which when started it simulates typing into another running app.
The second app is not mine so I cannot change its code.

Not sure if this is clear, Simply My app would be a button that when pressed types some text into a separate notepad app.

I am not even sure if this is possible and if it is where to even start looking.

Any pointers would be greatly appriciated

Comment: *"The second app is not mine so I cannot change its code."*. Then impossible for you to do that. except the second app accept certain request from your app

Comment: That will not work and I hope nobody will find a way to do so, because if this would be possible, You can manipulate too much....

Comment: would there be a way I could use the clipboard to store the text and then trigger the paste into the 2nd app? that way there is less of a security concern.